# Values in between brackets in function definitions

Tags: c

I've seen people do stuff like this before in C -

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[argc+1])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

What is the significance of the `argc+1` and what does it mean? Does it help prevent invalid pointers or what?

Comment: Cannot say that I have seen `char *argv[argc+1])` - Any reference

Comment: It means nothing, since the compiler will ignore it.

Comment: I found it. It was on Hacker News - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9019085 . " This allegedly helps prevent null pointers from being passed in, and presumably tells the analyzers and optimizers some things they should know."

Comment: @kaylum it looks like that's probably a duplicate.

Comment: *"This allegedly helps prevent null pointers from being passed in"* On the contrary, the C spec guarantees that `argv[argc]` *is* a NULL pointer. So if the compiler somehow enforced a non-NULL rule (which is doesn't), then that definition of `main` would be invalid.

Comment: as the dupe describes (briefly) if the array syntax is used for a function parameter **with keyword `static`** (only C99 or later) which this Q doesn't, it tells the compiler/etc the adjusted parameter must point to at least that many elements and thus must be nonnull; it does not require anything about the element values, here the pointers *in* `argv[i]`. As @user3386109 indicates the standard elsewhere requires `argv[0 to argc]` *in initial call to 2arg `main`* exist and `[argc]` be a null pointer and `[0..argc-1]` point to string values (necessarily nonnull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, this is not allowed in "classic" C (C89/90), since array size expression is not constant. It became legal in C99.

One the other hand, even in C99 the top-level array size in function parameter declaration is still ignored and the declaration is equivalent to

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

So, the only reason for that `argc+1` to be there is to serve as a self-documentation feature: it tells the reader that `argv` pointer points to the beginning of an array with `argc + 1` valid elements.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Unfortunately since a bunch of others (and myself) marked this as a duplicate my question already had an answer :P Thank you though